# Html, css , javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with icons and text. 
**want to align only text to the center of div while two icons to left and 4 to 5 icons to right of the div.**
Now, i aligned the icons properly but the issue is with aligning text exactly to the center of the div.
I temporarily fixed this using padding but it doesn't work with different resolutions.

can someone please help me in solving this issue.i added a images which is not exactly center to the div. i need the text to be exactly center of the and it should work with all resolution's

[image]

Comment: Please add your code for reference.

Comment: yes, someone can help by reading your mind :p

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're asking for, but maybe this will help :

I am using flexbox property `space-between` to align icon right and left and to center the text

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/victor_allegret/o98oh3mo/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="target">
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Centered Text
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<style>
#target { text-align: center }
#target i:first-child { float: left; }
#target i:last-child { float: right; }
</style>
```